# Prevent Double Form Submit within X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent double form submissions within a small window, then allow the form to be submitted again.

I wrote this script after looking at several examples, but the global variable is bugging me. I'd welcome any suggestions on improving it.

```
var aLockedForms=   [];
jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmit=  function() {

    jQuery( this ).submit( function() {
        if ( this.beenSubmitted )
            return false;

        this.beenSubmitted= true;

        aLockedForms.push( this );

        setTimeout( function() {
                        var domTarget=  aLockedForms.shift();
                            domTarget.beenSubmitted=    false;

                    } ,
                    1984 );

    });

};
```

After the DOM is loaded, I run the following:

```
$( "form" ).preventDoubleSubmit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the global variable, you're already using jQuery so why not just attach an attribute or class to the form?

```
jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmit=function(duration) {
    duration = duration || 1984;
    jQuery( this ).submit( function() {
        if ( this.hasClass("locked") ) return false;
        jQuery(this).addClass("locked");
        that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(that).removeClass("locked");
        }
        , duration );
    });
};
```

You may want to change the class name to something a little more unique, but that should work.

Comment: The this reference goes a bit strange in setTimeout.

Comment: I edited to alias `this` as `that`, see if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the entire thing in an anonymous function that you immediately execute:

```
(function() {
  var aLockedForms = [];

  ...
)();
```

---

**Edit:** I want to clarify that this is something you can do to eliminate global variables in the future. [Adam Tuttle's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7771/8891) is better in this case because it eliminates the variable entirely by properly utilizing the closure inside `setTimeout`.